# A "fuller" full_join in dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr

```r
k <- tibble::tribble(
  ~k_Name, ~Class, ~p_k,
  "IJP",   "A",    0.66,
  "IJP",   "B",    0.25,
  "IJP",   "C",    0.09,
)

xi <- tibble::tribble(
  ~xi_Name, ~Class, ~p_xi, ~k_Name,
  "1",      "A",    0.5,   "IJP",
  "1",      "B",    0.5,   "IJP",
  "2",      "A",    0.25,  "IJP",
  "2",      "B",    0.25,  "IJP",
  "2",      "C",    0.25,  "IJP",
  "2",      "D",    0.25,  "IJP",
)
```

If I `full_join(k,xi)`, the result misses the a raw for `xi_Name = "1"` and `Class = "C"`.
This `Class` does not exist in the original tibble `xi`, but I want the join to inherit it by the fact that both the tibbles have a `k_Name` column with values that matches (`"IJP"`).

Of course, the `p_xi` will be `NA`, because `Class = "C"` has no match when `xi_Name = "1"`

Expected output:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~xi_Name, ~Class, ~p_xi, ~k_Name, ~p_k,
  "1",      "A",    0.5,   "IJP",   .66,
  "1",      "B",    0.5,   "IJP",   .25,
  "1",      "C",    NA,    "IJP",   .09,
  "2",      "A",    0.25,  "IJP",   .66,
  "2",      "B",    0.25,  "IJP",   .25,
  "2",      "C",    0.25,  "IJP",   .09,
  "2",      "D",    0.25,  "IJP",   NA
)
```

Comment: Maybe `full_join(k,xi |> complete(xi_Name, Class))`?

Comment: No, because this will match `Class = D` with `xi_Name = 1`, which is wrong. `D` is not in `k`, nor in `xi %>% filter(xi_Name == 1)`. Also, this does not join the values of `p_k` and `p_xi` even when they exist.

Comment: Can you please show what output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k |>
  full_join(distinct(xi, xi_Name, k_Name), by = "k_Name", relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  full_join(xi, by = c("k_Name", "Class", "xi_Name")) |>
  arrange(k_Name, xi_Name, Class)
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#   k_Name Class   p_k xi_Name  p_xi
#   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 IJP    A      0.66 1        0.5
# 2 IJP    B      0.25 1        0.5
# 3 IJP    C      0.09 1       NA
# 4 IJP    A      0.66 2        0.25
# 5 IJP    B      0.25 2        0.25
# 6 IJP    C      0.09 2        0.25
# 7 IJP    D     NA    2        0.25
```